# Want to open a pdf file by clicking an image in my web page

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML and css. I want to have an image in my page so that if you click that image a pdf file should open. Please help me out with a clear code.....

Comment: *Please help me out with a clear code* - **NO**, show your code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="href://yourdomain.com/pathToPdf/pdflink.pdf">
   <img src="href://yourdomain.com/pathToimage/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

pdflink.pdf would be your link to the pdf.
image.jpg would be your link to the image.

If you add target="_blank" to the code it'll open in a new tab in your browser.

The code would then be:

```
<a href="href://yourdomain.com/pathToPdf/pdflink.pdf" target="_blank">
   <img src="href://yourdomain.com/pathToimage/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Comment: You're welcome @user3117864
If the answer helped, you could select it as correct answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="new.pdf"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="path/to/file/filename.pdf">
    <img src="path/to/image/filename.jpg" />
</a>
```

**Note:** "path/to/file/filename.pdf" refers to the folder paths you have to reach through to access where the pdf and the image files are.